# Laravel 5.8 custom timestamp column names not working as documented

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

**Nevermind, I'm a giant idiot.  I had two copies of the model.  I had modified one of the models to include the CREATED_AT/UPDATED_AT constants, but in my controller I was calling the other model.  I appreciate the time that people took to reply to this.  Will leave the question up in case others run into the same issue.**

According to the Laravel 5.8 [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), it is possible to customize the names of the columns used to store the timestamps in a table:

> If you need to customize the names of the columns used to store the timestamps, you may set the CREATED_AT and UPDATED_AT constants in your model.

Here is the example they give:

```php
class Flight extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
}
```

I am trying to get this working in my application (which is Lumen, if that makes a difference) and it is not working.  Here is my model:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExternalUsers extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ExternalUsers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'username';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    const CREATED_AT = 'createdAt';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updatedAt';
}
```

Whenever I try to update an existing row in the ExternalUsers table, I get this error message in the log:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'ExternalUsers.updated_at' in 'field list'

Am I doing something wrong here, or is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: How are you updating the existing row?

Comment: I'm a giant dumbass and was calling the wrong file.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have modified your model with the names of the timestamps fields make sure that you have these fields names in your database. In your case, your table `ExternalUsers` should have both timestamp fields: `createdAt` and `updatedAt` instead of the defaults fields of Laravel: `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: I was calling the wrong file.  It was totally my fault.  I appreciate the time you took to answer this.